# How to search two tables sharing a foreign key (I think I'm asking this right....)?

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, android-room, junction

**Dog entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "dog_table")
public class DogEntity {

  private int mId;
  private String mName, mBreed;
  etc..
}
```

**Toy entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "toy_table")
public class ToyEntity {

  private int mId;
  private String mName, mBrand;
  etc..
}
```

**DogAndToy join table entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "dog_and_toy_join_table",
    primaryKeys = {"mDogID", "mToyId"},
    foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
            entity = DogEntity.class,
            parentColumns = "mId",
            childColumns = "mDogID",
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        @ForeignKey(
            entity = ToyEntity.class,
            parentColumns = "mId",
            childColumns = "mToyId",
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    },
    indices = {@Index("mDogID"), @Index("mToyId")}
)
public class DogAndToyJoinEntity{

  private final int mDogID, mToyId;

  public DogAndToyJoinEntity(int mDogID, int mToyId) {
    this.mDogID = mDogID;
    this.mToyId = mToyId;
  }
  etc..
}
```

**DogAndToy data class**

```
public class DogAndToy {

  @Embedded
  public Dog mDog;

  @Relation(
      parentColumn = "mId",
      entityColumn = "mId",
      entity = ToyEntity.class,
      associateBy =
      @Junction(
          value = DogAndToyJoinEntity.class,
          parentColumn = "mDogId",
          entityColumn = "mToyId"
      )
  )
  public List<ToyEntity> toyList;
}
```

*notes: All dogs can have multiple toys, and toys can be associated with multiple dogs. Dog & Toy entities don't share any fields (eg - Dog doesn't have toyId, etc)*

I've been trying for a few days to wrap my head around

> how to query/get all dogs associated with one Toy (by name)

*I use the DogAndToy data class for display purposes in my RecyclerView.*

JOIN and INNER JOIN queries are baffling to me and I've been trying multiple variations but keep ending up with zero search results. Here's my most recent try:

```
  @Transaction
  @Query("SELECT dog_table.* FROM dog_table" +
      "INNER JOIN dog_and_toy_join_table ON dog_table.mId = dog_and_toy_join_table.mDogId" +
      "INNER JOIN toy_table ON toy_table.mId = dog_and_toy_join_table.mToyId " +
      "WHERE toy_table.mName LIKE :query")
  LiveData<List<DogAndToy>> findDogsByToyName(String query);
```

Can anyone suggest a step-by-step description of these queries in Android Room? Any of the JOIN articles/examples I find here or anywhere on the internets don't have a "join" (foreign key) reference...
Am I even trying this in the right manner?

**update**: *to clarify, I have FTS tables and my "basic" searches work fine (eg - search by name, etc)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :toyName with the variable

```
SELECT d.mName FROM dog_table AS d
WHERE d.mId IN ( 
  SELECT j.mDogID FROM dog_and_toy_join_table AS j
  WHERE j.mToyId = (
    SELECT t.mId FROM toy_table AS t
    WHERE t.mName = :toyName));
```

**EDIT**

TBH, no idea why it only selects one row. Maybe someone else can answer it.

It the mean time take this:

```
select d.mName
from dog_table d 
    INNER join dog_and_toy_join_table dt
        on d.mid = dt.mDogID 
    INNER JOIN toy_table t
        ON dt.mToyId = t.mId
    WHERE t.mName = 'toy1'
```

Comment: still no results :-(
Wait, I think I have it my query codes mixed up with my FTS queries.... let me try again

Comment: so it works! technically... It always returns a list of 1 result (first result in the table), when there could be hundreds
Any ideas?